# try& catch used to provide a value

Tags: try-catch

I used try and catch method in my program, but I did not procedure a value which user enter when an incorrect value is entered. For example user enter a string value and program says that please enter a number... then program do not allow that user enter a new value. What can I do? My codes are here. Thanks.

```
     try
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter column number: ");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            int columno = int.Parse(str);
            if (columno > 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("please enter a number between 1 and 20");
            }
            else
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < columno; j++)
                {
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                    {

                        int rndno = rnd.Next(1, 50);
                        Console.WriteLine(rndno);

                    }
                }
            }

        }
 catch

        {
            Console.WriteLine("please enter a number between 1 and 20", "Error");
                        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }



}
}
```

Comment: Tag your question with a programming language.

Comment: you mean you want the user to be asked to enter value until it's a correct one? or just close the app?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure for the language, probably C#, but it should be something like that:

```
Console.Write("Please enter column number: ");

int columno = 0;
while(true) {
    try{
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        columno = int.Parse(str); 
        if (columno < 21 && columno > 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    catch {}

    Console.WriteLine("please enter a number between 1 and 20", , "Error");            
}

    //Rest of the code
```

The problem is that you're catching the exception on your entire code instead of on input only, so you catch it and continue right after all the code. All the remaining part inside the `try` is not executed.